# Running Example Code for ViewPager Tutorial

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Simple question here.

I am wanting to develop a page turning animation for my application and I happened upon this excellent looking tutorial which appears to answer my every need:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

The only issue though is that I'm not sure how to run the example.  The tutorial gives the instructions "If you want to jump ahead and see a full working example, download and run the sample app and select the Screen Slide example." however the downloaded package doesn't contain any gradle files or anything that lets Android Studio know what to do.  Could someone tell me how one is supposed to import the supplied files into Android Studio.  I'm sure it's not hard, I just don't know how to do it myself and am having trouble working it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, why the down vote?

If it's a silly question by all means let me know and I'l ammend/remove it as appropriate but I don't actually see what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally worked it out.

I needed to *Import* rather than *Open* the project (which is in `File > Import Project...`).

I think this code example could have possibly originally been an Eclipse project hence the need to *import* it into Android Studio.  I'm not exactly sure why there was an '.idea' directory in the package if indeed it was an Eclipse project originally but what ever the reason Import worked a treat!

Comment: Glad it works for you. '.idea' directory is a directory for IntelliJ project setting. When you import it with Android Studio, the project will be treated as Android Studio project by restructuring it, hence the '.idea' directory is created. afaik

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that Android Studio uses the '.idea' directory.  What I was confused about was why there was an '.idea' directory in the downloaded package when it didn't seem to be an Android Studio project.  I finally found the answer here: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html#migrate-intellij

It seems the example was created as an IntelliJ project but not in Android Studio.  I didn't realize there were InteliJ Android projects that didn't use Gradle but, well, it appears there are and as it was the fix was as simple as selecting *Import* rather than *Open* :)